# Sheets - triggers not passing argument

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Trying to add a simple audit script into a sheet but the argument isn't being passed through when the trigger is being activated.  This results in `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')`.  Also using the debugging tool it's showing that 'e' is undefined.  I get the same issue when trying to add an onChange trigger.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var name = e.user.getEmail();
  var date = new Date();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var value = e.value;
  
  // Add a new row to the audit sheet with the change information
  var auditSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Audit");
  auditSheet.appendRow([sheet.getName(), row, col, value, name, date, "onEdit"]);
}
```

I've tried testing it in the app script project editor as well as testing an edit on the sheet.  Looking at the executions log, they are showing the triggers as 'Failed'

Comment: If you are trying to run these from the script editor `e` is undefined.  `e` is the event object passed to `onEdit()` or `onChange()` when the event occurs.

Comment: Before it had worked in testing through the script editor as well as on the sheet.  For some reason or another, the trigger stopped passing 'e' and it started throwing errors saying that 'e' was undefined.  I had literally watched the script work fine prior but for some reason it stopped passing the argument and declaring that the trigger had failed.

Comment: It works for me just as it's written.  However, it may not always get the user email

Comment: So if it didn't grab the email, how do I force that?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any installed `onEdit()` and check your script file to make sure you don't have multiple `onEdit()` script in the file.

Comment: I haven't installed any triggers and I've ensured that I deleted all triggers in the project manager. The only triggers I implemented were the ones through the project manager.  Still won't pass the argument.

Comment: The argument e is only generated when you edit the active sheet not when you call the function.

Comment: It worked for me too, have you tried with another sheet and see if you experience the same behaviour?